# Exponential Interpolation of x values to a specific range

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, linear-algebra

I have the following problem. I have an array with x Values. Now they should all casted to a new range of numbers by a exponential function. The function needs to be array friendly, so the input could be the whole array. I need a function where you could change the the range which should be changed and the range to which numbers they should be casted. Furthermore a fill value is needed if the x Values are outside the range, like scipy interp1d do it. I tried it like that:

```
def exponentialInter(x,border1,border2,interV1,interV2,fillValue):

    #x is the x Value array

    x = x.astype(np.float)
    mask1 = x<border1
    mask2 = x>border2
    mask3= np.ma.mask_or(mask1,mask2)
    x[mask3] = np.nan

    y = np.exp(np.log(interV1)+np.log(interV2/interV1)*((x-border1) / (border2-border1)))
    y = np.nan_to_num(y)

    return y
```

For a range which result in a positive exponential function, this is no problem, like for the case that all numbers between 0 and 5 should be casted to numbers between 2 and 20 :

```
print(exponentialInter(np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),0,5,2,20,0))

[ 2.          3.16978638  5.02377286  7.96214341 12.61914689 20.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

But I got serious problem if the number of range the x values should casted to is negative or result in a negative exponential function like for ranges:

```
interV1 = -1, interV2 =-15
interV1 = 1, interV2 =-17
interV1 = -20, interV2 = 20
interV1 = 20, interV2 = 2
```

How do I have to change my method, that it works for those cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exponential functions cannot produce negative numbers. There are several possibilities you can choose, but a simple one is just to apply a shift to the interval so it always starts on 1, then undo the shifting at the end. When `interV1 > interV2` you can negate both numbers and then apply this shifting, later undo. So in the end it could be something like:

```
def exponentialInter(x, border1, border2, interV1, interV2, fillValue):
    factor = 1 if interV1 <= interV2 else -1
    interV1 *= factor
    interV2 *= factor
    shift = 1 - interV1
    interV1 += shift
    interV2 += shift

    # Computation ...

    return (y - shift) * factor
```